# Retrieve Key Input before recording a users call when making calls within Twilio

Tags: twilio

We have currently developed a phone system for our call centre using Twilio (mainly c#, angular2 and typescript). Our company is currently in the UK but we have now started expanding out to the USA and because of laws in the US it looks like we'd need the ability to choose when we turn on the call recording. In the US people have to consent to recording the call before you can start recording them. I am trying to -  when we make an outbound call via twilio to first play a message and get the user to input a key on their dialer to consent to recording the call before continuing with the call. I have attempted to use the gather and say verbs after we have dialled out but this doesn't seem to work. Code below:

`

```
public override void ApplyAction(TwilioResponse response)
        {
                 var attributes = this.GetAttributes<DialAttributes>("attribute-");
            attributes.callerId = this.PhoneNumber;
            response.Dial(new Number(this.ReceiverPhoneNumber), attributes);
            response.Gather(
              new
              {
                  timeout = 10,
                  finishOnKey = '*'
              });
            response.Say("We record all calls - please press the star key to consent to call recording");

        }`
```

Comment: I work at Twilio. That should be the way to do it. Can you share the code, or at least the current call flow, and what exactly isn't working? Thanks

Comment: we have a response builder class that will generate a TwilioResponse depending on direction of the call, phone etc - So for Outbound calls we have an outbound class with the method ApplyAction that will create the twilio response for outbound calls - called off to the Dial and then after that gather and say but it still just dials the call connects and then it doesn't perform the other two actions - i will add the code in the next comment

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code, it's much easier to read. Thanks!

Comment: yes sorry im new to this

Comment: In your code, does the `<Say>` get nested within the `<Gather>`?

Comment: i have tried that but it did no say anything when the call gets connected with the consumer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The problem is that you are performing the [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) before the [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather)
 and [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say). If you want the user to approve the call first you need to nest the `<Say>` in the `<Gather>` and provide an `action` URL for the `<Gather>`. When the user presses a button as part of the `<Gather>` Twilio will make an HTTP request to the action URL with the results in the `Digits` parameter. Then you should return the `<Dial>` as the response to that request, if the user signifies agreement. This way you ask them first and then connect the call.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi Phil,

The problem is - this would work for inbound calls but we are also trying to implement this for outbound calls - so we would need to dial the consumer first and then play them a message and gather their key press before continuing with the call. When i tried to implement this yesterday i used the Gather and say before dialing but because it was an outbound call it was playing the message to me and waiting for my key input before dialling the consumer - this is not how we want it to work.

Thanks,
Danielle

Comment: Ah, in that case you want to use what's called a ["whisper"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/call-whisper) for the outbound call. You would dial yourself first and return TwiML that has a `<Dial>` and then a `<Number>` with the person your calling's number as well as a [`url` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-url). That URL attribute should point to the TwiML that does the `<Gather>` and `<Say>` and it is played when the person being called answers the phone, before they are connected to you.
Note, you will need different TwiML for in and outbound calls.

Comment: [This tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-screening/java/servlets) shows how to use a whisper to screen calls in Java. It's not exactly your use case, but it might help illustrate what's going on.

Comment: Thanks phil ill give that a go. I'll keep you updated, Thanks for your help

Comment: hi phil thanks for your help on this - once we have retrieved user input do you know if there is a way to whisper something to our call operator only to make them aware of the what the consumer has selected? thanks in advanced

Comment: You can whisper using the [`url` attribute on the `<Number>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-url).